# How to reverse a linked list using one pass by reference variable?

Tags: c++, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to reverse a linked list using recursion (not iteratively). Originally, I set my head pointer as a global variable so I don't need to return head. This version works fine, so I want to implement a version that takes head as a local variable. The code is as below:

```
void Reverse(node* &head, node *p)
{
    if(p == NULL) return; //nothing in list
    if(p->link == NULL)
    {
        head = p;
        return;
    }
    Reverse(head, p->link);
    node *q = p->link;
    q->link = p;
    p->link = NULL;
}
//some code to set local var head to a linked list
Reverse(head, head);
```

It works fine, but it seems so cumbersome. I have tried some ways to do it with just one variable but it doesn't work.

```
void Reverse(node* &head)
{
    if(head == NULL) return;
    node *p = head;
    if(p->link == NULL)
    {
        head = p;
        return;
    }
    Reverse(p->link);
    node *q = p->link;
    q->link = p;
    p->link = NULL;
}
//some code to set local var head to a linked list
Reverse(head);
Print(head); //output only last element in list
```

Is there any other way to implement it with just one pass by reference variable? Also, could you explain why the 2nd code outputs like it does? Thanks!**Edit:**
So it seems that this isn't such a good way to do it. So the last approach I can think of is to take a pass by value parameter and return the result(assuming head is local). I tried implementing it as such:

```
node* Reverse(node *p)
{
    if(p == NULL) return p; //nothing in list
    if(p->link == NULL)
    {
        return p;
    }
    Reverse(p->link);
    node *q = p->link;
    q->link = p;
    p->link = NULL;
    //control may reach end of non-void fucntion
}
```

but I can't think of a way to get around the "control may reach end of non-void function" problem. Any help?

Comment: Prefer functions that return results over those that return nothing and modify their by-reference arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution: you can just call your first function in `Reverse`:

```
void Reverse(node *&head) {
    Reverse(head, head); //may want to rename or make private
}
```

Comment: I guess it works, but I'm more curious whether there is a way to actually only work with one variable.

Comment: @TonyTarng because upon entering `Reverse(p->link)`, the automatic reference `head` therein no longer references the originating caller's `head` pointer. `head = p;` isn't setting the root-caller's `head` at all unless there is only one node (and thus no recursion). The very reason for the `head` parameter in the first example is to "carry" it down the recursion  depth until the end of the traversal is finally reached. If you print `&head` for each node traversed in the first example you'll see it is the same variable from the caller. That is *not* the case in the second example.